# CXF Webservice response with XML content

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I have an existing CXF Java webservice which returns a deep, complex, nested response type. Parts of the response type exists in the DB stored as plain XML message (the exact same XML what should get returned).

Example response type:
PartyResponse -> PartyRec -> PartyInfo
and PartyInfo structure is stored as XML in DB.

How could I return the response from Java, inserting the XML part without deserializing it to Java objects with JAXB just to serialize it again to XML via CXF right after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jaxws Provider's Payload mode.
See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/provider-services.html

Your service can then just return a Source object that is just a generic XML object. Something like shown below:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.ws.Provider;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider;

@WebServiceProvider(serviceName="EchoService", portName="EchoPort")
@ServiceMode(value=Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class EchoPayloadProvider implements Provider<Source> {
    public Source invoke(Source request) throws WebServiceException {
        // just echo back
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: in that case, I would need to serialize other parts of the response myself with JAXB, merge it with the XML fragment loaded from the DB and return it in Payload mode, right?